# Form Validation - Required attribute not coming when HTML content sent as email to Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, email, gmail

I am sending the following form as email in Gmail from c# (SmtpClient) to get the users comment.

```
<form id='RejectFeedbackForm' method='get' action="http://localhost:49309/Controller/Action">
    Reason for rejection<br />
    <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' required/><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

But Gmail omits the required attribute. I get it like this as email.

```
<form id="m_-8883071243854624425RejectFeedbackForm" method="get" action="http://localhost:49309/Controller/Action"
    target="_blank">
    Reason for rejection<br>
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="m_-8883071243854624425comment"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Any idea how to achieve the required validation? I can't use Javascript because Gmail omits that too.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?  please fix your tags.

Comment: did you try giving `required='required'`